# Jest inline testenvironmentsoptions not working

Tags: jestjs

For a few specific tests i need to have a different url in the jsdom than the globally set default value.

In Jest 28 the [feature to pass testEnvironmentOptions inline in a file](https://jestjs.io/blog/2022/04/25/jest-28#inline-testenvironmentoptions), was introduced.

When using a copy of the test from the Jest blog in my testfile

```
  /**
   * @jest-environment jsdom
   * @jest-environment-options {"url": "https://jestjs.io/"}
   */
 test('use jsdom and set the URL in this test file', () => {
   expect(window.location.href).toBe('https://jestjs.io/')
 })
```

It does fail with

```
 expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

 Expected: "https://jestjs.io/"
 Received: "https://jest.mijnmarkt.nl/"
```

In the jest.config.ts the following relevant exports are used

```
 testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
 testEnvironmentOptions: {url: 'https://jest.mijnmarkt.nl'},
```

Jest and jest-environment-jsdom version "^29.3.1" are used.

There are besides the blog article and commit documentation not much information or examples available. But it seems that the annotations are ignored. Any insights how to pass inline testenvironmentoptions ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the annotations are file-based and not test-based.
The annotations need to be at the top of the file, before any other statement or import.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 * @jest-environment-options {"url": "https://jest.nonauthdmain.nl/"}
 */
import {screen, cleanup, render} from '@testing-library/react'

import React from 'react'

....

describe('Authentication from nonauthorized domain', () => {
  test('use jsdom and set the URL in this test file', () => {
   expect(window.location.href).toBe('https://jest.nonauthdmain.nl/')
 })
})
```

Comment: you're right, it is a failure design.